# How to use One-Click Publish and Visual Studio to add an assembly to the remote server's GAC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, assemblies, gac

I'm using Visual Studio's one-click publish and web deploy to publish my .net MVC application to a remote server. This works very well. Now I'd like to have one of the assemblies installed into the GAC of the remote server.

How do I do this using web deploy and one-click publish?

Answer (score 1):

A ClickOnce-app can't install anything except itself. All prerequisites which VS creates inside bootstrapper setup.exe isn't actually ClickOnce. It just a bootstrapper.